# How can you build tolerance to neck muscle strains?

Tags: injury, pull-ups, rock-climbing, neck

Every now and then at climbing competitions I'll need to do pull-ups while my head is looking to the left or right. I've hurt my neck a couple times doing this. I get a muscle strain or pinched nerve in the back of my neck which hangs around for several days.

I've always heard that you should look forward or up while doing pull-ups to prevent injury. If I start practicing pull-up sets with my head turned to the side, am I going to build up a tolerance to strains or just create further injuries?

Comment: not an answer, but might have some valuable info: http://www.exrx.net/Lists/ExList/NeckWt.html

Comment: and this one: http://bretcontreras.com/neck-training-101/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My susceptibility to neck strains decreased significantly after I started focusing on overhead mobility.

For me that meant overhead presses, overhead squats, one-arm overhead pressing while in a squat, plus—and this is important—**all the mobility work necessary to support those exercises**. I suspect that other methods of increasing stability overhead would help too, such as Turkish get-ups, snatches, and windmills.

Comment: Makes sense, since I'm almost 100% working my overhead pull muscles, but rarely do any overhead push. Maybe this will alleviate the imbalance. Thanks, I'll give it a try.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a muscular imbalance thing, but rather an issue of full mobility in those positions across the shoulder girdle and neck, and stability within those positions.